# Android: How can I get notified for foreground applications (Packages) swaps

Tags: android, package, foreground

I want to listen - Get notified - when foreground application - Package in Android language - changes (Going to background - Which means different Package came in Foreground).

- I want to listen to this change from my Service.
- I want to listen to all packages / applications, not only my application.
- Working environment is: Android 4.1.2 (API 16 and forward).
- I'm not looking for using a timer to check every few seconds, as it's resources consumer.

Comment: There is no way to do what you want without polling the system at intervals to see which activity is in the foreground. Android doesn't broadcast any Intent or send any other signal that you could listen for to get this information.

Comment: Are you intending to listen to a particular app or do you want this to work for all apps?

Comment: @PeriHartman I want to listen for all applications.

Comment: Then, I think David answered your question.  Sorry for the disappointment :)

Comment: @PeriHartman Thank you all for your help, and nothing to feel sorry about it, you can't find everything in one thing :) P.S: Let's say in future I wan't to get notified when a specific application come in foreground, is it possible?

Comment: If you have the source code for that app - sure.  You can have it broadcast something during onResume().

Comment: Hey guys, what about this listener? OnGlobalFocusChangeListener(). I'm trying to let it work but without success.. Any advice?